# Wireless radio bricked, how can I access it from down here?

Tags: wireless-networking

My RB SXT 5hpnd r2 radio is installed too high for me to reach so I need to find a way to reactivate it from down here. It's a radio I own and have the user and password to it. I was in the settings and I was trying to move from Bridge to PPPoE mode and then it became unresponsive.

If you need additional info I can provide it.

Comment: You have not supplied any of the information required to help you.  You don't need to ask for help, the fact you asked a question, indicates you want help.  Remove meta commentary like "please help" because its just noise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a MikroTik SXT5 radio. It is powered by a PoE injector.  You can try removing power to the device and depending on whether your unwanted change was committed or not, it may start functioning again.

If that doesn't work you must reset the radio using the physical reset jumper. As described in the product's [Quick Start Guide](https://i.mt.lv/routerboard/files/SXT-5HPnD-qg.pdf):

> **Buttons and Jumpers**
>
> - RouterOS reset jumper hole (access through the plastic door) – resets RouterOS software to defaults. Must short circuit the metallic sides of the hole (with a screwdriver, for example) and boot the device. Hold screwdriver in place until RouterOS configuration is cleared.
> - RouterBOOT reset button (access through the plastic door)....Hold this button during boot time until LED light starts flashing, release the button to reset RouterOS configuration (same result as with reset hole)